# The best strategy to maximize the last number on a die.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

**Problem**

A player plays a game with the following rules. He throws a die until $1$ appears or he wishes to finish. The aim of the game is to maximize the last thrown number. What would be the best strategy and what is the expected number of the last throw.

**Ideas**
I reckon that after the first trow we need to look at the number. If it's smaller than $4$, it makes sense to throw the dice again as the probability of getting four and higher is bigger than the probability of getting two and one.

Comment: I need to answer the question - "What is the best strategy and the corresponding expected payoff?". So, yes.

Comment: Unclear re "maximize the last thrown number".  If you play the game 3 times, which do you *intend* is better: 1,5,6 or 4,4,4?

Comment: 1,5,6 could not happen according to the rules as the game stops after 1. Obviously, after 6 the player stops as he would not get a higher number if he continued. The payoff in the task is the number the last thrown die shows.

Comment: See my answer, which considers what is expected to happen if you play the game 3 **separate** times, which was also the *intent* of my note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n$ denote the strategy of stopping if you throw $n$ or more, and let $E_n$ be its expected value. Then whenever you throw, you have:

- a $\frac16$ chance of throwing a $1$;
- a $\frac{7-n}{6}$ chance of throwing $n$ or more;
- an $\frac{n-2}{6}$ chance of re-throwing.

And if you throw $n$ or more, your expected value is $\frac{n+6}{2}$.

So if $E_n$ is the expected value of strategy $S_n$, we have
$$E_n=\frac16+\frac{7-n}{6}\frac{n+6}{2}+\frac{n-2}{6}E_n$$

Now you can easily evaluate $E_n$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: So your answer agrees with mine that $E_4 = E_5.$

Answer (score 1):

If you roll a 4, you have a decision to make.

If you keep rolling until you roll a 1,5, or 6

then you should get each of those events 1/3 of time.

If you stop, you have accepted the 4.

So the decision whether to keep rolling comes down to whether
after 3 games you prefer

4,4,4 or 1,5,6

I don't see any way of justifying stopping after you roll a 3.